# How does netty handle not replied or lost SYN packets?

Tags: netty, netty-socketio

I am writing a TCP socket server with Netty.

How does Netty handle lost SYN packets?

I am assuming that when a client connects to my server netty will automatically send SYN packets now and then, in case the client connection hangs and becomes unresponsive to the SYN packets my server may send what will netty do?

Will it close the connection and invoke the `SimpleChannelHandler.channelClosed` method?

Could you please point me to the classes where SYN packets are handled (be it a TCP socket server or client)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259774/what-if-a-tcp-handshake-segment-is-lost .

Comment: thanks @Jabongg, but my question is whether or not netty sends SYN packets automatically when a connection is established or they have to me programatically explicit. I also wonder what would happen when a SYN packet is lost, Is it warranty that Netty will close the connection?

Comment: Low-level TCP connection management, including SYN handling, is done by the operating system.  Java, and therefore Netty, is not informed that a connection has been established until SYNs and the corresponding ACKs have been properly exchanged.